# MySql - can BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER insert into 2 columns?

Tags: mysql, triggers, referential-integrity

Can this trigger be changed so that the `sortorder` table gets 2 column values (`sortOrderId`, `sortOrder`) inserted?

How is the value of `sortOrder` found?

If it is known and can be inserted into `image` table then can it also be inserted into the `sortorder` table?

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

USE `nextcart`$$

CREATE
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost`
TRIGGER `nextcart`.`insert_sortorderid` 

BEFORE INSERT ON `nextcart`.`image` 

FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO sortorder SET sortOrderId = NULL, sortOrder = NEW.sortOrder;

    SET NEW.sortOrderId = (SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID());
END;
$$
```

CREATE TABLE sortorder:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `sortorder` (
  `sortOrderId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sortOrder` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`sortOrderId`),
  KEY `sort_order` (`sortOrderId`,`sortOrder`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_sortOrderId` FOREIGN KEY (`sortOrderId`) REFERENCES `image` (`imageId`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

CREATE TABLE image:

```
delimiter $$

CREATE TABLE `image` (
  `imageId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `imageFileName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imagePath` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageTitle` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageAlt` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageWidth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageHeight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `classId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `imageSizeId` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `isImageEnabled` bit(1) DEFAULT b'0',
  `sortOrderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`imageId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

ERROR MESSAGE:

> Error 1054: Unknown column 'sortOrder' in 'NEW' SQL Statement:
>   CREATE TRIGGER insert_sortorderid  BEFORE INSERT ON image  FOR EACH
>   ROW  BEGIN  INSERT INTO nextcart.sortorder SET sortOrderId = NULL,
>   sortOrder = NEW.sortOrder;  SET NEW.sortOrderId = (   SELECT
>   LAST_INSERT_ID()); END;   Error when running failback script. Details
>   follow. Error 1050: Table 'image' already exists SQL Statement: CREATE
>   TABLE `image` (   `imageId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
>   `imageFileName` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,   `imagePath` varchar(255)
>   DEFAULT NULL,   `imageTitle` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   `imageAlt`
>   varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,   `imageWidth` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
>   `imageHeight` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   `classId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL, 
>   `imageSizeId` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,   `isImageEnabled` bit(1) DEFAULT
>   b'0',   `sortOrderId` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,   PRIMARY KEY (`imageId`)
>   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no column named `sortOrder` in the `image` table.

So, the reference to `NEW.sortOrder` (on the insert statement in the trigger) is invalid.

---

To answer your first question: No. Since there is no value supplied for that in the INSERT statement (which fires the BEFORE INSERT TRIGGER), you don't really have a source for that value.

The easy option is to provide a default value for it.

If you want to supply a value for the `sortOrder` column, then one option is to add a sortOrder column to the `image` table, and then the value can be supplied in the `INSERT INTO image` statement. Then it would available in the trigger.

(The purpose of the `sortorder` table is not at all clear.)

Comment: Thank you for replying. I thought if I had a `sortorder` table I could sort any other `tableName` I think to create.. beit, a image, item name, tab description, it could boil down to any `element` at the end of the day right? Is it more precise instead to put a sortOrder column on ALL my tables (that need them) and be done with this problem?